# Gradle can not resolve com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker

Tags: android, google-analytics, dependencies

I'm going to Implement google Analytic V4 from this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-integrating-google-analytics-v4/).

I updated project dependency like this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
```

In my `AnalyticsTrackers` class unfortunately `Tracker` won't resolve.
I also tried to implement dependency from [google link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#set-up-your-project)
like this:

> Add the dependency to your project-level build.gradle:
>
> ```
> classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
>
> Add the plugin to your app-level build.gradle:
>
> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
> ```
>
> Now, you need to add a dependency for Google Play Services. Inside
>   your app's build.gradle add: compile
>   'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'

but still can not resolve `com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker`

Comment: The implementation you found on the link you mentioned is outdated.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I have an app with analytic v2 that all out dated but can resolve Tracker and works fine.

Comment: because your version is not 8.4.0 and google service is also 2.0.0-alpha6 ....this is updated one...if you change the versions...it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Add the plugin to your app-level build.gradle in same sequence:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Also you need to add google-services.json received from google account

you can try sample from https://github.com/googleanalytics/hello-world-android-app

Comment: where you added google-services.json in your project